# how can i run my java program without eclipse?

Tags: java

I have a console based java minesweeper. How can i launch this on my desktop without opening it in my eclipse program and hit run? 
The program consists of a couple classes and there is an user input in the console. are there any standard methhods?

Tried this: export > executable jar file. that didn't work..

thank you!

Comment: `that didn't work..` How did you test it? What errors you get?

Answer (score 3):

The best method for executing your program outside of an ide is to export it as a runnable jar file.

However since your program sounds to be console based, it will run without showing anything.

The way to run the jar file is to go into a command line, find it, and run this:

```
java -jar myprogram.jar
```

This will show the output through the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Start+r 
"cmd" enter

> java -version (if stuff pops up it's all good and you have java configured on your machine) 
>   java -jar "file\location\of\jar\file"